# Accumulate JSON Values in Python Dictionary as Array

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have JSON File that has this format

```
{ 
"links": [
{"source":"0","target":"1","weight":1,"color":"white"},
{"source":"0","target":"2","weight":1,"color":"yellow"},
{"source":"0","target":"3","weight":1,"color":"white"},
]
}
```

I want to collect all `target` for a single `source` like this:

`{"source": 0, "neighbors": ["1","2","3"]}` where `neighbors` are all the collected `target`

Here's my Code

```
import json

with open("linksGr.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

collectDict = {}
for obj in data["links"]:
    if (collectDict["source"] == obj["source"]):
        collectDict["neighbour"] = obj["target"]
```

I just need a way to accumulate all targets for each source instead of there being multiple sources as I have done here

```
collectDict["source"] = obj["source"]
collectDict["neighbour"] = obj["target"]
```

Any help would be appreciated a lot. I am sure there is some basic concept and a simple way that I am missing here. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), to map from source to a *list* of targets, like this:

(I added some data to have multiple sources)

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = { 
"links": [
{"source":"0","target":"1","weight":1,"color":"white"},
{"source":"0","target":"2","weight":1,"color":"yellow"},
{"source":"0","target":"3","weight":1,"color":"white"},
{"source":"5","target":"7","weight":1,"color":"white"},
{"source":"5","target":"8","weight":1,"color":"yellow"},
{"source":"6","target":"9","weight":1,"color":"white"},
]
}

collectDict = defaultdict(list)
for obj in data["links"]:
    collectDict[obj["source"]].append(obj["target"])

print(dict(collectDict))
```

Output:

```
{'0': ['1', '2', '3'], '5': ['7', '8'], '6': ['9']}
```

**EDIT:** Here's another method using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), *assuming the links are ordered by sources (otherwise, just sort it before)*

```py
from itertools import groupby

collectDict = {k: [t["target"] for t in g] for k,g in groupby(data["links"], lambda obj: obj["source"])}

print(collectDict)
```

Comment: Thank you SOO much. This is exactly what I wanted. Highly appreciated. 

I actually just did the exact same thing where I appended the list but I did not know about the `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: yes they are Fortunately ordered by sources such as `source 0` comes before `source 1` and so

Answer (score 1):

```py
data = { 
    "links": [
        {"source":"0","target":"1","weight":1,"color":"white"},
        {"source":"0","target":"2","weight":1,"color":"yellow"},
        {"source":"0","target":"3","weight":1,"color":"white"},
        {"source":"5","target":"7","weight":1,"color":"white"},
        {"source":"5","target":"8","weight":1,"color":"yellow"},
        {"source":"6","target":"9","weight":1,"color":"white"},
    ]
}

collected = []
for obj in data["links"]:
    source_matches = [item for item in collected if item["source"] == obj["source"]]
    if len(source_matches) == 0:
        source_match = {"source": obj["source"], "neighbour": [obj["target"]]}
        collected.append(source_match)
    elif len(source_matches) == 1:
        source_matches[0]["neighbour"].append(obj["target"])
    else:
        raise BaseException()

print(collected)  # [{'source': '0', 'neighbour': ['1', '2', '3']}, {'source': '5', 'neighbour': ['7', '8']}, {'source': '6', 'neighbour': ['9']}]
```

Not very elegant, but does the job.

If you don't really need the format `{"source": 0, "neighbors": ["1","2","3"]}` I recommend the above solution using `defaultdict`. If you need this format, you could also build it from the output of the `defaultdict` solution.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why people vote for this answer and not for mine O.o

Comment: Yours requires pandas as dependency which I personally am not so familiar with and which is probably not necessary for such a problem. Also downvotes may come from before the edit you made; before the edit you had `"source"` hardcoded to `0` ;-)

Comment: The above solution is perfect for me as I dont really need the format, I just need the source node and its neighbours. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
import pandas as pd

result = [{"source": source, "neighbors": df["target"].tolist()}
          for source, df in pd.DataFrame(data["links"]).groupby("source")]
```

Comment: @Adam.Er8 haha don't worry, I'm not going to downvote your answer! Simply I can't understand why my answer is wrong. Could you help me?

Comment: this works well but it took 3 times as much time as @Adam.Er8 s answer, is it because of the pandas import ?